# How refresh a widget/List View widget

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I'd like to force ListView to reload the data after I click on a Button Input. It looks like a trivial task but cannot find how to refresh a widget or even a page/location in gosu

Comment: Is your button intending to Add data to the LV or is it more like a refresh button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have new data loaded in the db or another resource that you need to fetch, checkout something like the "Refresh" button on the Underwriting Rules Import/Export Status screen in PolicyCenter.

```
<!-- From RuleExportImportStatusScreen.pcf --> 
      <ToolbarButton
        action="null"
        id="RefreshButton"
        label="DisplayKey.get('Button.Refresh')"
        tooltip="DisplayKey.get('BizRules.RuleExportImportStatusScreen.RefreshTooltip')"/>
```

If instead you need to update the ListView after onscreen data entry, update the variable in the PCF that the RowIterator is calling.

```
<RowIterator
  editable="false"
  elementName="account"
  value="items" <!-- Update the nodes that RowIterator uses --> 
  valueType="entity.Account[]">
```